# what is the maximum concurrent user/sec does magento support?

Tags: user

how can i know what is the maximum concurrent user/sec does my site support? I tried finding answer of this question but unable to get

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are so many variables which must be specified. On a toaster, maybe one or two ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There's little point quoting peak figures, Magento will handle as much traffic as you have the budget and expertise to facilitate.

At larger scales, as the bottleneck shifts, you often find that Magento looks less and less like Magento as some functionality is stripped/replaced.

Instead, I'll quote what the demands of typical stores from a hardware perspective.

- A standard Magento demo store is capable of delivering roughly 230 uniques per GHz, per hour.
- A typical web store, with admin user activity, development activity, product addition/deletion can see this degrade by around 100%, to 115 uniques per GHz, per hour.
- A store with a poorly built/heavy template can further reduce the figure by another 100-200%, to 50 uniques per GHz, per hour.

The above is assuming a traditional ecommerce store with balanced distribution of window shoppers, engagers and converters.

Safe to say, you can happily see millions of visitors per day - given you're asking on Stack Exchange, I'd assume you are well under this threshold.

Source: https://www.sonassi.com/help/magestack/cpu-sizing