# What are the limitations of Magento 2 CE?

Tags: magento2, magento-community, server-setup, optimization, pagespeed

I've recently got a Magento 2 website project and I'm not sure which edition of Magento that I should go with.

I Know Magento 2 EE has many advantages over the CE edition, but I need details only in terms of performance.

I don't want to tell the client why EE is better than CE, but want to tell him the limitations of CE like

- how many concurrent users can be there.
- how many no. of products, SKU, categories, images, etc.
- best hosting for Magento 2 so site speed will be much faster.

I know concurrent users are dependent upon the server but don't know what is the limitation for Magento 2 CE.

Hence please can somebody explain to me what are the limitations of Magento 2 CE.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Ask Magento sales. I'm sure they are happy to tell you limitations.

Answer (score 1):

[what is the maximum concurrent user/sec does magento support?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87753/what-is-the-maximum-concurrent-user-sec-does-magento-support)
https://aionhill.com/how-many-products-can-magento-handle
https://www.hostingadvice.com/reviews/magento/